# Convert local users to AD domain users Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, users

I created a bunch of local accounts on machines at work before we had AD set up.  Now I'd like to consolidate all the local accounts into domain accounts.  For instance, I've got user "Fred Jones" on 2 computers.  I can create an AD user Fred Jones and log into the machines with the AD account, but is there a way I can log into the computers using the AD account but see all the settings, files, and such that were set up locally?

Bonus if I could change the username from Fred Jones to FJones.

Thanks!

Some of the machines are running Windows Server 2008 R2 and some are Win7.  The AD is on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using Windows Easy Transfer on the local account, and then the domain account.

The username should be easy to change within active directory users and computers for AD and within local user management for the Local account.

Don't forget you can always login to the local account using localhostname\username and network using domain\username (or username@domain)

Comment: Hi Regan, we don't really care if it's an old question so long as you're adding something new and useful to it. And remember that it's about helping anyone who comes across the question, not just the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the local profile to the domain profile.

Comment: How do I copy the local profile to the domain profile?

Comment: Access the System properties on the server, select the Advanced system settings, click the settings button in the User Profiles section, find and select the local profile, click the Copy To button, browse to the domain profile folder, click the Change button under the Permitted to use section, type Everyone or type the domain user name in the Select User or Group windows, click OK on all open windows.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions.  I tried logging in as the Domain Administrator to the computer and the "Copy To" button is disabled when I select the local user.  Do I need to be a local user to make the change?

Comment: You shouldn't need to but try it. Also, the user who's profile you want to copy is not logged in, right? If after logging in as a local admin you still can't copy the profile then reboot the server and try again. It may be that the profile you're trying to copy hasn't been completely unloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Trying it right now (first reboot was unsuccessful)

Comment: I've tried resetting multiple machines multiple times and logging in as the domain administrator as well as local administrators and the Copy To is always greyed out.  Any idea on what I might be missing? Do I need to run in a special mode?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4440702b-b045-403b-9c0d-08b6e314131c/windows-7-trying-to-copy-a-user-profile-the-copy-to-button-is-always-grayed-out-and-the-user?forum=w7itprosecurity